# Interstitial Ad for DFP not showing Fullscreen in ADMob iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, admob, iphone-5, google-dfp, interstitial

I am implementing the interstitial ad using Google's AdMob SDK. The Ad shows fine on iPhone 4S and lower. However on iPhone 5, the ad leaves a blank space at the bottom since its not resized properly.

The Ad Size is 320x480. According to their [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/advanced), The SDK will handle rendering the creative correctly on screens. If I create an Ad of Size 320x568, i get error as "No Ad to Show".

How Can I support full screen Ad on iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0):

The interstitial overlay is full screen, but the creative being served through DFP (probably just an image) does not span the entire screen - so you're getting some white space at the bottom which is the background of the overlay. To get your creative to span the entire screen, you may want to write some html that can handle a bigger screen size.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by writing html. Can you be more specific please. Are you referring to writing javascript?

Comment: yeah, an html/javascript creative. Are you using the DFP UI to manage your own creatives?